# How to set X-Frame-Options Header in wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, security, x-frame-options

I have hosted a website which is created using Wordpress.

I am getting a security alert saying `"X-Frame-Options Header Not Set"`, but I can't figure out what that means.

Can anyone explain what this warning is about, and give me a solution on how to stop it from occuring?

Comment: Maybe you can use this? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/recommendations-for-x-xss-protection-x-frame-options-x-content-type-nosniff

Answer (score 31):

Here's an easier one-liner to set `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` that works, add the following to the functions.php file in your current Wordpress theme:

`add_action( 'send_headers', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );`

Comment: This would be my preferred option as this can be added to your functions.php in the theme and doesnt require editing the WP core or the .htaccess file.

Comment: but you get an error when send_frame_options_header is already declared somewhere else in wp-includes/function.php - selecting a different name in your themes function.php does help neither, since you will have set multiple x-frame-options. you need somehow remove the initial headers.. but how to do that without touching the core functions.php (this should never be touched)

Comment: I had to use 'init' instead of 'send_headers' to make this work.  i.e.  `add_action('init', 'send_frame_options_header');`

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1** : Go to **wordpress-root/wp-includes/functions.php** 
and search for "X-Frame-Options" and you will find the function

```
function send_frame_options_header() {
@header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' );
}
```

If X-Frame-Options is not defined inside your functions.php file, you just paste the code inside functions.php. 
To Prevent the site from cross-frame-scripting in Wordpress use X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN.

**Option 2:**

Or you can set X-Frame-Options from the .htaccess file which is situated inside the root folder of wordpress. Just paste the below code inside .htaccess file.

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Editing Wordpress core is heavily discouraged. There is a better solution.

Comment: Never under any circumstances edit WordPress core or use Option 1.

Comment: Why not use `wp-config.php` for this??

Answer (score 2):

I was having this error on a Multisite installation and it prevented subsites to show plugin details (when you click "View details" and it opens a popup).

I solved adding this to my `wp-config.php`:

```
header('X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.MYDOMAIN.com');
header('Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.MYDOMAIN.com');
```

Update:
This only works for subdomains, for alias domains I had to whitelist everything with `https://*`.

Answer (score 0):

In any PHP application the header can be set before page content is sent. This is done using the header function.

```
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```